# Convertir un formato de moneda a número sin signo de dólar

Tags: php

¿Cómo convertir un formato de moneda a número sin signo de dólar usando solo PHP (sin usar JavaScript)?

Quiero convertir $ 1.000,55 a 1000,55. He encontrado info pero para hacer el proceso inverso. ¿Es posible? ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Answer (score 1):

Creo ver un **espacio** después del signo `$`, de ser así, la función sería como se ha dicho en la respuesta, pero incluyendo el espacio en el array de caracteres a reemplazar, ya que dejar el valor con el espacio en blanco podría ser problemático en muchos casos, por ejemplo, si el valor obtenido va a ser insertado posteriormente en una base de datos:

---

#### Opción 1: [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php)

```
/* 1. Con str_replace: Recomendada en este caso */

    function str_replaceChars ($str){
      return str_replace(array("$", " ", "."), "", $str);
    }
```

---

#### Opción 2: [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace.php)

Aprovecho para indicar que también se podría hacer con la función `preg_replace`, aunque para este caso sencillo la **opción 1** sería la más adecuada.

```
/* 2. Con preg_replace: Recomendada para reemplazos más complicados */

    function preg_replaceChars($str)
    {
        return preg_replace('/\$|\ |\./','',$str);
    }
```

---

#### Resultado

#### [**`VER DEMO`**](http://rextester.com/RPND15565)

Probando con estas dos cadenas:

```
echo "OPCIÓN 1: str_replace\n\n";
echo str_replaceChars("$ 1.000,55")."\n";
echo str_replaceChars("$ 1.900.000,55")."\n";

echo "\n\nOPCIÓN 2: preg_replace\n\n";
echo preg_replaceChars("$ 1.000,55")."\n";
echo str_replaceChars("$ 1.900.000,55")."\n";
```

el resultado de ambas opciones es el siguiente:

```
OPCIÓN 1: str_replace

1000,55
1900000,55


OPCIÓN 2: preg_replace

1000,55
1900000,55
```

Answer (score 0):

Aunque bien existe una funcion en PHP, llamada [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.number-format.php), la cual sirve para los **formatos de moneda** (*agregar decimales y todo ello*), lo que seria mas facil para tu caso *(ya que la funcion number_format no soporta el signo peso **$***), seria hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
<?php

$valor = "$1.055,55";

print convertirFormato($valor) . "\n";

/**
 * Esta funcion elimina el signo $ y el punto.
*/
function convertirFormato($valor){
  return str_replace(array("$", "."), "", $valor);
}

?>
```

> Resultado:
>
> 1055,55

Lo que hacemos en este ejemplo es usar la funcion [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php), para **eliminar** los dos caracteres que no nos sirven *($ y .)* y asi retornar su valor ya convertido.